# Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 - Wifi connection

Tags: networking, server, wireless

So, quick story. I found an old laptop and decided to convert it into a server. Just to see if I was able to.

Installation went smoothly.

The problem was when connecting to the network, it just... Didn't. So I've been googling and tweaking all night and my eyes are too tired and I decide to simply ask.

The wireless network card is a Qualcomm Atheros AR242x.

The interfaces file reads as follows:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
   address 192.168.x.xx
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 192.168.x.xx
   wpa-ssid foo
   wpa-psk boo
```

I then run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Which fails.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your wireless interface really wlan0? Confirm: `iwconfig` You need to add: `dns-nameservers 192.168.x.xx 8.8.8.8` or similar. Finally, I think the method to restart the interface is: `sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -v wlan0`

Answer (score 1):

Because of persistent interface naming which started in Ubuntu 16.04, I suspect that your interface name is not wlan0. Confirm:

```
iwconfig
```

You may find that it is something like wlp3s0 or similar. If so, amend the `interfaces` file to read:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto wlp3s0
iface wlp3s0 inet static
   address 192.168.x.xx
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 192.168.x.xx
   dns-nameservers 192.168.x.xx 8.8.8.8
   wpa-ssid foo
   wpa-psk boo
```

Check in the administration pages of your router or access point to find the range of addresses used for DHCP; select an address for your static server outside that range so that there is no collision.

Either reboot or retstart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown wlp3s0 && sudo ifup -v wlp3s0
```

Did you connect?

```
ping -c3 8.8.8.8
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour The searchers will appreciate it.

Answer (score -3):

There is a static IP address set on the machine. To fix that, first let's open the terminal:

```
ctrl-alt-t
```

Copy/paste the following few commands into the terminal.

Next let's use chili555's command (which he mispelled) to verify the correct interface:

```
ifconfig
```

Now,  let's reach out to the router and say hello, with the verbose switch on to see what happens:

```
sudo dhclient -v
```

Type in your root password.
You should see lines for an IP address request and offer in the output
Now, let's release the static IP address (with -v to see what is going on):

```
sudo dhclient -v -r
```

No need to type in your password again for this session.

On some variants of linux this will bring the network interface down and not renew the IP address. If this happens, you can now simply reconnect to the wireless network with your GUI Network Manager like you did the first time, or use chili555's ifdown/ifup command (not sure of his accuracy on that, never used it myself).

If you are still having issues, the next thing to do is open the laptop up and make sure the wireless antenna is connected and not broke. You see: the antenna goes through the hinge and extends up around the screen. Sometimes when laptops age, that wire can get damaged in the hinge. Simple enough to reattach, but it can be difficult to open a laptop with hidden screws and such, so please youtube the procedure for you model.

If it became disconnected, reconnect it and try again. If it is damaged, you can either replace it, or get a USB Wifi adaptor. Ofcourse no need to open the laptop to use a USB adaptor!

Source:
https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001078.htm

Comment: I didn't misspell it at all. Also, typically, a server will have no GUI and therefore no Network Manager. `sudo dhclient -v` will not connect with wireless since no SSID nor WPA password has been given.

Comment: He's connected to his wireless as is output shows. He even said he entered the password and connected. However his machine has a previously set static IP address that (in my opinion) might be conflicting with another device on his network (i.e his DHCP server on the router gave out that IP just before he adopted this laptop and the static IP happens to be the same). Changing it to Dynamic by releasing it would fix this.  Just bringing the interface up as you suggested would have no effect. Also I had forgotten about iwconfig so I'm sorry. So why the down vote!?!?!?! Please chill out chili555.

Comment: His post doesn't say he connected at all; it says: "The problem was when connecting to the network, it just... Didn't" That's clear to me. He didn't connect. I downvoted because your answer is wrong in three respects.

Comment: @Akadine You're the one that needs chilling out. Please take your time to read the questions (this is not the first time) before jumping into answering mode. I already commented in the other one where you went completely off-target.

Comment: Love you guys for answering quickly.

Comment: It connected during the installation, in which it actually has a GUI of sorts. After that, nothing connects. Will try your answers and post when done.