# how can I connect to wifi net automatically after ubuntu startup

Tags: networking

My PC has an ubuntu server 16.4.3. I have installed a USB wifi module. Now I use
`wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`

I see the USB wifi can connect to the wifi network correctly.

But I have to do it manually. I want my PC can connect to wifi network directly after it boot-up. I tried to add `ifconfig wlan0 up dhclient wlan0` in `/etc/rc/local`, but it doesn't work. And there is also no "/etc/NetworkManager" in my system.

How can I realize this action?

Answer (score 0):

Because of persistent interface naming which started in Ubuntu 16.04, I suspect that your interface name is not wlan0. Confirm:

```
iwconfig
```

Please amend the `/etc/network/interfaces` file to read:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
   wpa-ssid <your_router>
   wpa-psk <your_secret_key>
```

Reboot. Did you connect?

```
ping -c3 8.8.8.8
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

If you did not connect, you may be able to get some clue as to what went wrong with:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -v wlan0
```

You may find that it is more convenient to assign a static IP address to the server so that you can ftp and ssh into it. If so, please check here: [Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 - Wifi connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/942074/ubuntu-server-16-04-2-wifi-connection/942424#942424)

Comment: Thanks. I checked with iwconfig. it is wlan0 unassociated Nickname:"<WIFI@realtek>". Mode: auto Frequency =2.412Ghz access point: Not-assiociated.  I also edit the /etc/network/interfaces as you mentioned. Unfortunately the wifi still didn't connect to the destination WIFI module at system startup. By the way for some reason I have to use the 4.4.0-87 generic recovery mode each time. Does the recovery mode has some limitation for wifi module connection ?

Comment: If your interface is wlan0, then your file should be as I will show in my answer edit.